# PHP - Short hand if statement with a date format with weird output

Tags: php

I am using a short hand notation of an if statement to format a field. If the field is an empty string I leave it as an empty string, if not then I am trying to format it to a proper datetime format so it can be inserted into a mysql db. here is my php code

```
$date = ($date == '') ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) : $date;
```

for some reason when the $date string is not empty it is returning it int he format 'm/d/Y' example: 04/01/2010

When I pull the code out of the shorthand if

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
print($date);
```

it is formatted correctly like this 'Y-m-d' or 2010-04-01. Does anyone know why this happens? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a bit of a stab in the dark here at what you were trying to accomplish, but you might have more luck with this:

```
$date = ($ts = strtotime($date)) ? date("Y-m-d", $ts) : '';
```

This will attempt to parse any incoming date string, and fail to an empty string if the date was unparsable.

Note that it's important to do a check on strtotime's ability to parse a date, because date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) will return a date somewhere around 1970 if $date doesn't contain a parsable date.

e.g.:

```
$ php -r 'var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("thisisnotadate")));'
string(10) "1970-01-01"
$ php -r 'var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01/01/1901")));'
string(10) "1970-01-01"
$ php -r 'var_dump(date("Y-m-d", strtotime("01/01/2048")));'
string(10) "1970-01-01"
$
```

strtotime can only handle dates that fit in a 32 bit timestamp, which limits it to 1970 - 2038.  Additionally, some date formats may be ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

you confused the arguments of your ternary operator, just switch them, or change the equality operator to check for inequality:

```
$date = ($date !== '') ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) : $date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you describe, `$date` must have already been set elsewhere in the script using the `m/d/Y` notation. In that case, the ternary operator leves `$date` untouched.

When you get rid of the shorthand, that `m/d/Y` string is being forced into a timestamp by `strtotime`, and then into a proper `Y-m-d` string by `date()`.

Comment: nope it has not, I have check and it is defiantly happening in the shorthand if statement.

Comment: @McN can you show an example value of `$date` before this code is executed?

Comment: $date = '4/01/2010'; 

is what it prints out to be so I guess you are right, the input box is setting it to that, I guess the function is just not working for some reason when its inside the shorthand if.

Comment: @McNabb the logic of your code is flawed. You are formatting the date *only if it is empty*. If `$date` is set, it will go unformatted.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your statement is:

`If $date is an empty string, pass that empty string as a timestamp to the string to time function.  Pass that to the date function.  Otherwise return the contents of $date.`

Perhaps you intend:

```
$date = ($date == '') ? date("Y-m-d") : $date;
```

Comment: My intention is that if it is an empty string then keep it an empty string, if not then formate it using strtotime then the date function. I would need the strtotime in there to properly format it for mysql

Comment: @McNabb your code is doing the reverse right now. You need to turn them around.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you're doing something you don't need to (using ternary syntax).  From one of your comments `My intention is that if it is an empty string then keep it an empty string, if not then formate it using strtotime then the date function. I would need the strtotime in there to properly format it for mysql`

```
if($date != '')  // leave it alone if it is an empty string
{
    $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
}
```

(**Important note** - I haven't touched PHP for years, so syntax may be off, but the principle is the same)